# Is it permissible for an extension to output a file to the installation location of the extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am a VScode extension developer 'Multi Color Highlighter'.
In the current version it has a SVG file with 6 color icons and displays them in a TreeItem.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=456ken.multicolorhighlighter

I am considering updating it to add more colors, but I cannot determine if this is the correct manner for an extension.

1. the user enters the color code and the name of the color in the settings screen.
2. generate the svg file.
3. make the generated svg file the icon of the TreeItem.

Is it permissible for an extension to output a file to the installation location of the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think VS Code does not restrict you when you write to the local folder where your extension is installed. Only the file system itself could prevent that to happen.